# SP2010 upgrade to 2013 behaviour for link correction within office documents

Tags: 2013, upgrade

I am currently testing upgrade methods from SP2010 Server to SP2013 Server using the detach, attach and upgrade method.

At some point in the process it seems to have edited all links within office documents that point to other documents within SharePoint to the new location.

I.e. a link within a document on the 2010 system was `http://dmz-spwfe01/Docs/blaa.docx` and post upgrade the link has been changed to `http://dmz-sp2013wfe01/Docs/blaa.docx`

The original links are not relative and have just been copy and pasted by admin staff.

I would like to understand where and how this process occurs. And if possible to replicate this process outside of the normal method for upgrading web applications from 2010 to 2013.

My upgrade process in more detail:

- Original DB is backed up
- DB is restored as new DB
- New web application is created in new SP Farm
- Restored DB is mounted onto web app
- DB is converted to claims auth
- Web application is upgraded to 2013 from within SP

Thanks!